# Max or min of a vector with strings containing only numbers in r. Precedence of 'stringed' numbers in a vector

Tags: r, sorting, max, min

I have a vector containing numbers in quotes (so they are actually strings), and I am trying to figure out the max and min of the vector. For example, in the vector `x <- c("5", "12", "7")`, according to R, `max(x)` is 7 and `min(x)` is 12. In this other vector, `y  <- c("1","12","13","14","15","10","38","19", "60")`, `max(y)` is 60 and `min(y)` is 1. There seems to be a contradiction here. I have tried this several times and each time, I get weird and even more contradictory results. Also, `sort(x)` gives  `"12", "5",  "7"` as the result. This doesn't make sense too. Could someone help me explain what's happening? Thanks!

Comment: When sorting strings, R starts with the first character of the string, and then uses later characters to break ties if needed. "12" starts with "1", so it sorts lower than "5" or "7"

Comment: If you want to treat number as numbers, use a `numeric` data type. If you keep them as strings they will be sorted/compared alphabetically.

Comment: I guess it is clear to you know what was going on. One solution (if you really want to keep them as strings) is padding, example: `sort(sprintf("%*s", max(nchar(x)), x))`. You could also check out `stringr::str_pad()`.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are sorted alphabetically. We can verify the consistency of the ordering you observe by changing the strings of numbers to strings of letters, with 0 being a, 1 being b, etc.:

```
x <- c("5", "12", "7")
y  <- c("1","12","13","14","15","10","38","19", "60")

digit_to_letter = function(x) {
  x = strsplit(x, "")
  lets = lapply(x, function(d) letters[as.integer(d) + 1])
  sapply(lets, paste, collapse = "")
}
```

Binding the original number strings to their "equivalent" letters and then sorting, we can see that the ordering you observed is the same as the familiar alphabetical ordering, just applied to numbers. Similarly, the min and max are consistent with the alphabetical ordering. You may have noticed similar ordering, for example, in a directory on your computer if you have files with names that start with numbers.

```
x_example = cbind(x, digit_to_letter(x))
y_example = cbind(y, digit_to_letter(y))

x_example[order(x), ]
#      x        
# [1,] "12" "bc"
# [2,] "5"  "f" 
# [3,] "7"  "h" 

y_example[order(y), ]
 #      y        
 # [1,] "1"  "b" 
 # [2,] "10" "ba"
 # [3,] "12" "bc"
 # [4,] "13" "bd"
 # [5,] "14" "be"
 # [6,] "15" "bf"
 # [7,] "19" "bj"
 # [8,] "38" "di"
 # [9,] "60" "ga"
```

If you want to use numbers as numbers, use `as.numeric()` or `as.integer()` to convert your number strings to a more appropriate class.

One final example to illustrate a bit better:

```
z = as.character(c(1, 2, 10, 12, 100, 101, 121, 1000, 9))
cbind(z, digit_to_letter(z))[order(z), ]
 #     z            
 # [1,] "1"    "b"   
 # [2,] "10"   "ba"  
 # [3,] "100"  "baa" 
 # [4,] "1000" "baaa"
 # [5,] "101"  "bab" 
 # [6,] "12"   "bc"  
 # [7,] "121"  "bcb" 
 # [8,] "2"    "c"   
 # [9,] "9"    "j"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are working with strings.

To address your specific problem you can use the `destring()` function available in `taRifx` package.

See the code below:

```
x <- c("5", "12", "7")
install.packages("taRifx")
library(taRifx)
y <- destring(x)
sort(y)
```

This will destring the values and now when you ask for:

`min(y)` will give you 5

`max(y)` will give you 12

Comment: `min` and `max` give the **alphabetically** first and last elements, not the first and last elements of the vector. And recommending `taRifx::destring` would be a lot more compelling if you compared it to a built-in alternative like `as.numeric` or (in OP's case) even `as.integer`. What does `destring` do that these simpler, dependency-free functions don't?

Comment: I agree. I'm just used to the command and the package as I use it frequently.

Comment: Yeah, you got me a little confused there @DataSharkie. But it's clear now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just using other functionality of the package and got used to using the `destring()` function @rev_tesh

Comment: Welcome to SO @DataSharkie, I edited your post a little to help improve it.

Comment: Thank you @snoram